# iOS 15 rendering issues related to Dimensions API

Tags: react-native

## Summary

Some customers who have upgraded to iOS 15 (Released 2021-09-20) are
experiencing rendering issues for components relying on window dimension
information from `useWindowDimensions` or `Dimensions.get('window')`.

For users on iOS 15 after a fresh app launch, `useWindowDimensions` and
`Dimensions.get('window')` would return either 0 or a negative value.
Depending on how these APIs were used in a component, the regression would
last until the next app active / other Dimensions set event in the best case,
and in the worst case would not be able to be resolved.

I've opened a [Pull Request with React-Native to track on GitHub](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/208).

## Detailed Design

On iOS, RCTDeviceInfo.mm signals the RN-side to update its set Dimensions
dictionary if certain iOS lifecycle events happen, such as application did
become active and accessiblity events.

I suggest adding another listener for `RCTContentDidAppearNotification` in
RCTDeviceInfo.mm. Below is the diff:

```
--- node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules/RCTDeviceInfo.mm
+++ node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules/RCTDeviceInfo.mm
@@ -14,6 +14,7 @@
 #import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
 #import <React/RCTUIUtils.h>
 #import <React/RCTUtils.h>
+#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
 
 #import "CoreModulesPlugins.h"
 
@@ -71,6 +72,11 @@
                                                name:RCTUserInterfaceStyleDidChangeNotification
                                              object:nil];
 
+  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
+                                           selector:@selector(interfaceFrameDidChange)
+                                               name:RCTContentDidAppearNotification
+                                             object:nil];
+
 #endif
 }
```

The `RCTContentDidAppearNotification` event is already emitted by React's iOS library when
the React Native bundle has been initialized and the root app component view can be added
and displayed in `RCTRootView.m`'s view. Emitting this event insures the RN side is ready
to receive dimension update events and that components can reliably get a value they
expect for the window size.

## The Ask

How many others have experienced this issue and what was your solution/workaround to prevent iOS 15 rendering issues where content either was 'squished' or failed to display at all?